# Javascript - add a new DIV above a range of spans

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/highlighter-cv2kv?file=/src/index.js

I have a bunch of spans for every word in a phrase. I want to be able to create highlights based on a start and end time (every span has those details in dataset). Highlights need to be laid above the corresponding spans.

So far I've been able to highlight the start and stop word but I need to highlight every word between that interval.

Current state:

[image: current state]

Desired state:

[image: desired state]

Any ideas on how can I do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: can you share your codebase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dataset` and `querySelectorAll`

[**Working Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/highlighter-forked-jg47l?file=/src/index.js)

```
for (let range of ranges) {
  parent.querySelectorAll('.will-play').forEach (span => {
    if (span.dataset.start < range.start || span.dataset.end > range.end) {
      return;
    }

    let highLightParent = document.createElement("div");    
    let highlight = document.createElement("div");
    let pos = getPos(parent, span);
    highlight.style.cssText = `position: absolute; top: ${pos.top}px; left: ${pos.left}px; width: ${span.offsetWidth}px; height: ${span.offsetHeight}px; background-color: yellow; opacity: 0.5; z-index: 1`;

    highLightParent.appendChild(highlight);    
    parent.appendChild(highLightParent);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have an i idea for you less js more css, with that you only need to toggle the class `playing` and will highlight the words:

```
    body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.will-play {
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.will-play.playing::after {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: "";
}
```

I forgot the JS :

```
let ranges = { start: "80.9", end: "87.48" };


let spans = [...document.querySelectorAll("span.will-play")];

spans.map((item) => {
  if(item.dataset.start>=ranges.start && item.dataset.end<=ranges.end){
    item.classList.add('playing')
  }
});
```